# Querying from a Hard-Coded List MySql

Tags: mysql

How can I do this? I want to query from a hard-coded list?

```
select (222,
333,
444,
555,
666,
777,
777,
88,
999,
099) as imageids
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create multiple rows, each containing one image id:

```
select 222 as imageid
union select 333
union select 444
union select 555
union select 666
union select 777
union select 777
union select 88
union select 999
union select 099
```

or return a comma-separated string with all image ids:

```
select group_concat(222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 88, 999, 099) as imageids
```

Note that a value of `099` will be returned as `99` because it will be treated as an integer. If you need to preserve leading zeros, you should use string values (i.e. `"099"` instead of `099`).

Comment: Note that `group_concat` will truncate the string after `group_concat_max_length` bytes, so it won't work with arbitrarily long id lists, but it should be good enough for smaller lists.

Comment: I am sorry, but I wanted all those rows as separate rows!

Comment: Then you should use the `select ... union select ...` approach. My comment on strings vs. integers will still apply, i.e. to return `099` you will need to make it a string `"099"`, because numbers are returned with leading zeros stripped.